# My Python code is always showing Attribute Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

my python program shows attribute error. I couldnt solve it yet. Can anyone help?

This is my main code: https://github.com/ocecer/python/blob/master/sayisal_test.py

this is my module code: https://github.com/ocecer/python/blob/master/sayisalLotoModule.py

this is the error: AttributeError: module 'sayisalLotoModule' has no attribute 'row_list'

Comment: In the file sayisalLotoModule.py, you wrote a function def results(url): You have to call it to get the row_list.  Change the line if chosenNumbers in say.row_list: to if chosenNumbers in say.results(url):

Comment: please copy piece of code here. then tell us which line got the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems quite clear - your module doesn't have an attribute called `row_list` it only has a function called `results`. Internal to that function, a variable called `row_list` is used, but that's irrelevant.

I suspect the line

```
if chosenNumbers in say.row_list:
```

should read:

```
if chosenNumbers in say.results(url):
```

Comment: Module code is making a list of the following link and saving it in **row_list**

[link](http://lotobayisi.com/Sayisal-Butun-Veriler.aspx) 

i want this line `if chosenNumbers in say.row_list:` to seek for the row list in module code if the chosenNumbers have been chosen in real lottery game before.

Comment: also when i change the code into `if chosenNumbers in say.results(url):` it is writing all the row list in the code screen. and it doesn't look good. Sorry i am amateur in python

Comment: Your `results` function has several `print` calls in it - that's why values are getting printed out. Maybe take those out?